# how to record testcase using selenium in IE

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium.

My application is only IE compatible.

I know that we can run test cases in any any browsers using respective drivers but ***is there any way that we can use to record test case using selenium IDE in Internet Explorer*** **??**

Comment: Why, in 2014, is someone writing to be JUST IE compatible?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Some customers only use a single browser/platform and therefore there is no need to test on any other combination.

Answer (score 7):

We have implemented our own Recorder which will be used only for recording in Internet Explorer. It is a javascript file.

The concept is to add listeners to each object in the source code of the GUI of web page.
Below code helps you to do that. As soon as the page is loaded these listeners will be added. When you perform click action, all its properties will be captured.

Here i have given an example of adding listener and getting properties of the object of type "SELECT", you can do the same thing for other types of objects.

```
    var added_MClistener = false;     
    var tagn = dObj.tagName;    
            if(tagn == "SELECT")
                  {
                     dObj.attachEvent("onchange",so_showObjInfo);
                     dObj.added_OClistener = true;
                     dObj.so_prevBGColor = alll[i].style.backgroundColor;
                }
            if(tagn != "OPTION" && tagn != "SELECT" )
              {  
            dObj.added_MClistener = true;
             dObj.attachEvent("onclick",so_showObjInfo);
             dObj.so_prevBGColor = alll[i].style.backgroundColor;
             }
    function so_showObjInfo(e) {

    if(pause)return;
     if(isActive)return;
var preE = e;
    var e =e? e:window.event;
var ele=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;

    activeObj = ele;
    var eltagn= activeObj.tagName;
var currentNode=activeObj;
    var path=[];
while(currentNode){var pe=getNode(currentNode);if(pe){path.push(pe);if(pe.indexOf('@id')!=-1)break;}currentNode=currentNode.parentNode;}var xpath="//"+path.reverse().join('/');
    var fff=0;
    var xpath;
    while(currentNode){var pe=getNode(currentNode);if(pe){path.push(pe);if(pe.indexOf('@id')!=-1){fff=1; break;}if(pe.indexOf('@name')!=-1){fff=1; break;}}currentNode=currentNode.parentNode;}if(fff==1){xpath="//"+path.reverse().join('/');}

   var acurrentNode=activeObj;
    var apath=[];
    while(acurrentNode){var ape=agetNode(acurrentNode);if(ape){apath.push(ape);}acurrentNode=acurrentNode.parentNode;} var axpath="//"+apath.reverse().join('/');
var el=activeObj;
     var cssPath = cssselect(el);
     if (cssPath!=null)
     {
     cssPath="css="+cssPath;
     }
     var objval=activeObj.value;
     var objname=activeObj.name;
    var objidd=activeObj.id;
}
```

In this way we can add listeners to the objects on the webpage and get their properties. Now its up to you what to do next. You can either write it in an excel like we did(in a particular format) or you can create a notepad file.

Hope it helps....

Comment: How would one go about using this?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE is only available on Firefox. There is noway to record your test on IE using Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Recorder is for Firefox. Record with Firefox replay on ie. Tweak script as needed

Comment: His application is only ie compatible, your answer may not be useful in this context

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam It's the correct answer because there is no recorder for IE. What the questioner ask is simply not possible.

Comment: @singe31 I was meaning to this statement "Record with Firefox replay on ie. Tweak script as needed" as the OP mentioned it is not compatible other than IE, So how can we record when the application is not functional in Firefox

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam either don't record because it's not possible or make the application compatible with other browsers. These are the only solutions here.